# Database name and RIA Services

Tags: c#, .net, database, domainservices

Is it possible to get the **database name** within a `DomainService` of the RIA Services?

i.e. I have got

```
public partial class MyAppDomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<MyAppEntities>
```

This line `this.ObjectContext.Connection.Database` doesn't has any appropriated information.

How do I can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to Entities uses a conceptual model between the actual data source connection.
What you are looking for is:

```
((System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)this.ObjectContext.Connection).StoreConnection.Database
```